# How to create a Qt Creator project (.pro) file equivalent to existing Makefile

Tags: qt, makefile, qt-creator, gnu-make

There is a project which is build via `make` command, where the `Makefile` is provided. Following are the `Makefile` contents:

```
TARGETT=gnulinux
OROPATH=/usr/local
CXXFLAGS=-I${OROPATH}/include -DOROCOS_TARGET=${TARGETT} -Wall
LDFLAGS=-L${OROPATH}/lib -Wl,-rpath ${OROPATH}/lib -lorocos-taskbrowser-${TARGETT} -lorocos-rtt-${TARGETT}

all: main

main.o: main.cpp
    $(CXX) -c main.cpp $(CXXFLAGS)

AHRS.o: AHRS.cpp AHRS.h
    $(CXX) -c AHRS.cpp $(CXXFLAGS)

main: main.o AHRS.o 
    $(CXX) -g -o main main.o AHRS.o $(CXXFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS)

clean:
    rm -f main orocos.log .tb_history *.o
```

But I'm used to use `QtCreator`. I know that `QtCreator` constructs its own makefile from the project (.pro) file during build process. So, I think, relevant information must be copied from the `Makefile` contents (above) into a `Qt Creator` project file to allow `QtCreator` to generate the compatible makefile. Right?

Given the `Makefile` above, how should the .pro file look like?

And in the end of this process I'll be able to work from `QtCreator`.

Comment: Learn CMake, it's a standard for C++ now. QtCreator can open CMake projects normally. Template for Qt: http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/qt/1991/cmakelists-txt-for-your-qt-project

Comment: May I ask a CMake file equivalent to the .pro (provided below by @KubaOber)? I did some research about CMake and found it more difficult then qmake for the kind of projects I use to deal with.

Comment: The orocos has a CMake manual (currently on http://www.orocos.org/wiki/orocos/toolchain/getting-started/cmake-and-building). If you get it right with CMake, then the project will compile/cross-compile for different OSes and processor architectures (notice how it uses `find_package` instead of directly specifying the path). Don't think I can write an example, because the setup procedures for orocos are overcomplicated and there are no Debian packages ready to go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Given the Makefile above, how should the .pro file look like?

Like this:

```
TEMPLATE = app
TARGET = AHRS # the desired filename of the executable goes here
OROPATH = /usr/local
INCLUDEPATH += $${OROPATH}/include
O_TARGET = gnulinux
DEFINES += OROCOS_TARGET=$${O_TARGET}
QMAKE_RPATHDIR += -L$${OROPATH}/lib
LIBS += -L$${OROPATH}/lib 
LIBS += -lorocos-taskbrowser-$${O_TARGET} -lorocos-rtt-$${O_TARGET}

SOURCES += main.cpp AHRS.cpp
HEADERS += AHRS.h
```

Note that Qt Creator doesn't construct anything. qmake does. The project files are qmake projects, not Qt Creator projects. You don't need Qt Creator at all to build your project. You can do it from the command line using nothing but Qt and the compiler/binutils:

```
# assume that the source is in AHRS-source subfolder
mkdir AHRS
cd AHRS
/path/to/Qt/bin/qmake ../AHRS-source
make -j
# now we can run it
./AHRS
```